# Chrome crash on Windows server container

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

I'm running a windows docker container on a Windows machine using the following command:

`PS C:\> & 'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe' --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222 --enable-logging --v=1 "localhost:3000"`

Chrome processes will start up and then error out with the following logs:

```
PS C:\> [0413/103634.151:ERROR:network_change_notifier_win.cc(226)] WSALookupServiceBegin failed with: 0
[0413/103634.167:VERBOSE1:webrtc_internals.cc(117)] Could not get the download directory.
[0413/103634.167:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(871)] MSM::InitializeMaybeAsync([this=00005B6400335E00])
[0413/103634.167:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(871)] MDM::MediaDevicesManager()
[0413/103634.167:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(871)] MSM::MediaStreamManager([this=00005B6400335E00]))

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/browser/8fb20519-4faf-412b-ad7c-c848c5d86458
[0413/103634.406:ERROR:network_change_notifier_win.cc(226)] WSALookupServiceBegin failed with: 0
[0413/103634.453:ERROR:dxva_video_decode_accelerator_win.cc(1461)] DXVAVDA fatal error: could not LoadLibrary:
 mf.dll: The specified module could not be found. (0x7E)
[0413/103634.453:ERROR:dxva_video_decode_accelerator_win.cc(1461)] DXVAVDA fatal error: could not LoadLibrary:
 mfplat.dll: The specified module could not be found. (0x7E)
[0413/103634.453:ERROR:dxva_video_decode_accelerator_win.cc(1461)] DXVAVDA fatal error: could not LoadLibrary:
 msmpeg2vdec.dll: The specified module could not be found. (0x7E)
[0413/103634.453:ERROR:dxva_video_decode_accelerator_win.cc(1465)] DXVAVDA fatal error: could not LoadLibrary:
 dxva2.dll: The specified module could not be found. (0x7E)
[0413/103634.453:ERROR:dxva_video_decode_accelerator_win.cc(1469)] DXVAVDA fatal error: could not LoadLibrary:
 msvproc.dll: The specified module could not be found. (0x7E)
```

The virtual machine info is as follows:

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft
OS Version:                10.0.17763 N/A Build 17763
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Server
```

This seems similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59807553/chrome-is-closed-with-error-errornetwork-change-notifier-win-cc141-wsalookup) but the internet connection works and I can connect to various domains/ips/ports. Also, if the [call for WSALookupServiceBegin](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:net/base/network_change_notifier_win.cc;l=224?q=network_change_notifier_win.cc) fails, I don't believe it should crash the browser. My guess is that there is some graphics/media libraries not available in this windows server instance but I am otherwise unsure what this error may be coming from. Any ideas?

Same results when using no flags: `PS C:\> & 'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe' --enable-logging --v=1`

Comment: What about the simplest solution - adding the missing DLLs to the same directory your `chrome.exe` is located?

Answer (score 0):

If your base image is 2019 core or newer, this is due to missing fonts in the image. They were removed after 2016.
Check out [this](https://github.com/gantrior/docker-chrome-windows) repo on how to install the missing fonts

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same issue before. Are you using windowsservercore base image?

From my side, I think that it's because of missing the microsoft media foundation feature. And after changing the base image mcr.microsoft.com/windows/server:ltsc2022, it works, because it enables that feature.

Here is the related stackoverflow for more detail, https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-Containers/issues/260.